# Wires are not color coded- need to find line/load/neutral/ground

Tags: wiring, switch

I am trying to replace a dumb light switch with a smart one and stupidly forgot to photograph the old one before removing it. Now I have four wires, three of which are black, hanging out of the box and need a plan to figure out how to hook the new switch.

If this can be eyeballed, I would appreciate any guidance (or any help troubleshooting/inferring from the state of the box)!

[image: Image of the relevant box]

Comment: One black is the hot from the panel.  It will hot all the time the breaker is on.  The other two blacks are switched blacks.  They should be dead when the switch is off.  Guessing is bad when using electricity, so use a multi meter or non contact voltage tester to find the hot.  It is a good thing it was not a three way switch.  They can be very hard if you need to guess to connect them up without pictures of before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have any outlets or other fixture are out of power?  My guess is this is very typical wiring: 1)  power in, 2) power out to the next downstream device and switched power to the fixture.   If you find an outlet outlet not working, plug a high usage device (like a space heater or hair dryer) and measure resistance across each pair **POWER OFF** of course.   If you get very low resistance on one of the pairs....that goes to the downstream device....which would mean power out from the switch box.   Then turn the power back on and **carefully**  measure for voltage (not resistance) across the other two pair, the power in cable should be about 120volts.

Best practice is to connect the power-in and power-out wires using a wire nut with a pigtail to the smart switch If the smart switch has wires you could get by simply using the connection to the hots using the same wire nut...not best practice

The bare copper wires are ground.  I noted that there are 3 neutrals (the white wires) which makes me pretty darn sure it's a typical wiring pattern...again: power-in, power out and switched power to the fixture.   You'll probably have to get into all those neutral connections because most smart switches require a neutral connection.